# Short exact sequence of group of Hodge classes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm from a foreign country, I don't speak well English. Sorry.

My question is :

$X$ and $Y$ are subvarieties of a smooth projective variety $M$ such that $M=X \bigcup Y$. I would like to know if we can construct a short exact sequence $$ \mathrm{Hdg}_k ( X \bigcap Y ) \to \mathrm{Hdg}_k ( X ) \oplus \mathrm{Hdg}_k ( Y ) \to \mathrm{Hdg}_k ( X \bigcup Y ) \to 0 $$ such that $ \mathrm{Hdg}_k ( X ) = H^{k,k} ( X ) \bigcap H^{2k} ( X , \mathbb{Q} ) $ is the group of Hodge classes.
Can you tell me if you know some references about this subject?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Crossposted on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150007/short-exact-sequence

Comment: No need to apologize for the english, I think.

Comment: This is essentially a Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the group of Hodge classes?

Comment: This is what i try to know in reality.  :-)

Comment: There is an answer to the question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150000/group-of-hodge-classes